# Navigator not showing anything

Tags: react-native

My navigator wasn't rendering anything (only a white screen) so I have reduced it to bare minimum and still get nothing. Someone please help.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      AppRegistry,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      Navigator
    } from 'react-native';

    class MyApp extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
            <Navigator style={styles.container}
                initialRoute={{ title: 'My Initial Scene'}}
                renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
                    <Text>Hello</Text>
                }}
            />
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
      },
    });

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

Comment: That code looks pretty straight forward and good to me. I've seen text hide behind the iOS Carrier and Wifi icons when things are setup like that. Might look up there behind those. This is, of course, assuming you are in the iOS simulator.

Comment: Im using android, i have tried centering text and also rendering other components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a solution here:
https://rnplay.org/apps/0bw98Q

First, you don't need extra curly brackets after `=>`

Second, when you apply `alignItems: 'center'` or `justifyContent: 'center'` to the Navigator, it behaves not as you expect it to. It's better to use an extra View which would give you an expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Your render scene function in `Navigator` should return the `Text` component.

```
renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
    return <Text>Hello</Text>;
}}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in Chrome to see if the renderScene function gets called?